# this.props.array.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm learning react and am trying to render an element for each user in an array that I have defined, when I go to test it my browser throws an error saying **this.props.users.map** is not a function, I have done things similar to this before I don't understand what I am missing.

**In the parent component**

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users:[],
            chosenUser:undefined
        }
        this.currentUser = this.currentUser.bind(this);
    }    
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('/api/users')
        .then(results =>{
            this.setState({
                users: results.data
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
render(){
        return <>
        <Users users={this.state.users} chosenUser={this.state.chosenUser}/>
        </>
    }
```

**In the child component**

```
render(){
        return<>
        <h1>Users rendered</h1>
            {this.props.users && this.props.users.map(user =>{<li key={user._id}><button onClick={() => this.props.chosenUser}>{user.name}</button></li> // generate a button for each user
            })}
        <p>Not on the list? Don't worry, were not super exclusive, you can make a character here!</p>
        <NewUserForm newUser={this.addNewUser} name={this.state.name}/>
        </>
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like `results.data` is an object add a `console.log(results.data)` before you set the state and inspect the object

Comment: tell whats the result of  `result.data`

Comment: it is an  object but I set it as an array in the state? that is exactly it, it returns [Object, object]

Comment: @Trisitian It's free to add a 'debugger' in the render function of the child component, then you could inspect the props.users and check what the exact type it is. Another option is install react-devtool which offer the live state/props  monitor for you.

Comment: @Trisitian, Please update the ```results``` you fetched from get method.

Comment: @Tristian as you said that it is object, so you have to choose two option . Either you can send result as array format from backend. And if it is not posssible then change existing code, i.e handle object data accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

**this.props.array.map is not a function** occurs when you are trying to map something that is not **Array**

```
axios.get('/api/users')
        .then(results =>{
            this.setState({
                users: results.data
            });
        })
```

make sure `results.data` is **Array**

Answer (score 0):

`map()` method is just for **Array** and i think that the results from api you call don't return an Array.
So, `this.props.users` won't be an Array and it throws that Error.

I recommend checking your called api (/api/users) and see what the result is. It should be an Array

Hope it helps

[More info on map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

You need to always validate your data as this will ensure that your app doesn't suddenly break. Use [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check if users is indeed an array.

```
render(){
    return<>
      <h1>Users rendered</h1>
        {Array.isArray(this.props.users) && this.props.users.map(user =>{<li key={user._id}><button onClick={() => this.props.chosenUser}>{user.name}</button></li> // generate a button for each user
        })}
    <p>Not on the list? Don't worry, were not super exclusive, you can make a character here!</p>
    <NewUserForm newUser={this.addNewUser} name={this.state.name}/>
    </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you have more than one value in your state, you won't want to overwrite the other values in this case `chosenUser:undefined`. That is why you need to first clone the state before setting your `users`.
2. Your initial state is an empty `Array` but `Axios` returns a `JSON` object which means you are setting the value of users to Object.

Your code should look like this.

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/api/users')
    .then(results =>{
        this.setState({...this.state, users: [...this.state.users, results.data]
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

And you can use your `map()` function to loop over each item.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the property 'users' received by the child component is not an array at the moment. We all don't have the full code/api access permission so you have to do debugging by yourself. The good news is debugging is pretty easy in a React application. Let me show you how I debug usually.

1. Put breakpoints or add 'debugger' statement close to the code where the issue occurs, in your case it might be the render function. Then next time the render function is executing, the debugger will take the control and you are free to check anything you want to know.
2. Install the [React Developer ools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en). After it is installed(you have to reload the app) successfully, you will see new taps on the Chrome dev tools along with internal taps like Application. Choose the 'Component' tab and then you will see all the details(props/state/children, etc) of the component you want to inspect.

And, I strongly recommend you start to use props-types to declare the exact shape of each of the properties the component may receive.

Good luck.

Some docs which may help you:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html